# how not to count included associations in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a model in sequelize which is associated with two models. I have defined a controller to query the table and include along with the associated models and count the results too. In essence, the parent table has 7 records while my result count also counts the associated models which is not meant to be.

```
exports.getAllGasStocks = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { count, rows: results } = await GasStock.findAndCountAll({
    limit: 2,
    offset: 3,
    order: [['id', 'DESC']],

    //I don't want these fields to be counted as they being counted now
    include: ['gasVariety', 'orderedGasStocks'],  
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    count: count,
    results,
  });
});
```

Please, could someone help not to count the associated fields as commented in the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct option:

```
  const { count, rows: results } = await GasStock.findAndCountAll({
    limit: 2,
    offset: 3,
    order: [['id', 'DESC']],

    //I don't want these fields to be counted as they being counted now
    include: ['gasVariety', 'orderedGasStocks'],
    distinct: true,  // Required for counting issue
  });
```

Comment: So, please mark the answer to help everyone else.